# Motivation for building small self-teleporting 'medicbots'

Tags: internal-consistency, technology, robots

The design of these bots is an ellipsoid 5 inches long and 3 inches in diameter. They contain antimicrobial agents, some first-aid supplies, and a syringe that can extend through a tiny hole in the casing, which is black. They have a (apparently) seamless door to allow access to the supplies, loading of the syringe, and repair. And, of course, they teleport - either to a pre-set location or to the location of a 'calling device'. The purpose of the bots is to provide medical help when without supplies, though a certain organization uses it once to inject a person with a DNA-modifying virus.

What would the motivation of a wealthy, secret, and very scientifically advanced research organization be to build these? Note that they would keep the bots for their own use, and not sell or distribute them. And what could be some other uses, utilizing the small teleporting devices in the bots?

**UPDATE**

I can't delete this question, and I've no wish to keep a question that has garnered me several downvotes and curt notifications that 'your question has been put on hold.' Could someone please delete it for me? As I've said, the site has apparently been set on not allowing me to delete a question that I DO NOT WANT TO KEEP.

Comment: This sounds like Idea Generation, which would be off-topic.

Comment: I already have the idea, but I need to have a reason that the medicbots would be in the world in the first place.

Comment: I understand that. Poke around a bit on meta (http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/522 is a good starting point) and you'll find a bit more about Idea Generation. It's pretty much about "Why would [X] happen?" questions; your question appears to be one of those questions.

Comment: Again, I need _a reason for the idea to be there_, not the idea itself. Think of it as 'why would this corporation have the idea?'.

Comment: Wick, did you read the link I gave you? The reason you're searching for still qualifies as an idea.

Comment: Could you edit it to a more relevant question (or help me to do so)?

Comment: Hm. Perhaps you could ask about what the bots could be used for. That doesn't ask for the initial conditions; it asks about the future. You would of course have to specify what your world is like, but that version might be okay.

Comment: I've edited it to show their purpose

Comment: And asked about other uses & technology based off of them.

Comment: A potential counter: why would you NOT build such extraordinary creations?  What is the opportunity cost for this ultra secretive organization?  If there's no real measurable cost, then the reason could be as simple as "because they could."

Comment: Sounds quite speculative. This could be relevant by specifying the question. Possibly by asking how this would be possible, or what implication there might be. As this question stands it is not suitable for this community.

Comment: You can't delete a question with an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to get closed by the anti-idea-generation police, so I am racing to provide at least a partial answer.

Start with your teleportation technology not being compatable with life.  Nothing living can go through.  So since you can't bring the patients to the hospital, bring the hospital to the patients.

Now add a pan-global plague that is wiping out our genetic diversity.  Your drones were created to distribute a cure as quickly as possible to save as many different kinds of people as possible.  Fortunately, they were designed and manufactured before the plague started or we would all have been lost.